# Type 'Promise<Document>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Document>'

Tags: mongoose, typescript, promise

I'm using Promise to void callback hell.

But I met the typecast issue.

here is my method or function define:

```
findById(entityId: string): Promise<mongoose.Document> {
    return this._model.findById(entityId).exec();
}
```

The typescript tips some error about:

> [ts] Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
>     Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
>       Type '(onFulFill: (result: Document) => void | U | Promise, onReject?: (err: any) => void | U | P...' is not assignable to type '{ (onfulfilled?: (value: Document) => TResult | PromiseLike, onrejected?: (reas...'.
>         Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
>           Property 'catch' is missing in type 'Promise'.

I want to know how to void this issue?

Comment: seems like there are two different `Promise` types you are using. The one you declared to return in the function signature isn't the same as the one which `exec()` returns.

Comment: this._model is mongoose object, exec() will return Promise<mongoose.Docment>

Comment: From what I've seen, mongoose is using the A+ promise library, and that's a different implementation than the native implementation. You seem to be mixing them both

Comment: here is my code: https://github.com/JeffreyChan/loma_online_testing
you can see, I am not using other implementation promise, just mongoose promise.

Comment: that's a lot of code, i'm not going to go over all of that. please just update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: thanks anyway. I think I found problem. Cause my install RXJS, But I am not using it. so VSCODE tips error, but gulp can compile right.

could you help me check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351696/mongoose-unique-validator-not-working-no-throw-error
mongoose-unique-validator not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for different promise types being used. In my case, one file was importing `es6-promise` while the other wasn't.